# Migrating windows 8 license from one machine to another

Tags: windows-8, migration, legal

Is it possible to migrate windows 8 license from 1 machine to another. I purchase one license and installed it in my old PC. No i purchased a new one and i want to transfer that license to my new machine, Can anyone please help me to transfer the same in my new machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did just that 3 weeks ago. Microsoft's phone-in is very simple and slick but make sure you have your serial number. When asked the question "is this your first computer or activation" or something along that line make sure you say you are doing your first activation. If you say it is your second the line will cut off. I learned that one the hard way but on my second try I said it was my first PC and everything went smoothly from then on. You have to enter a bunch of characters but you will get a second chance if you make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough yes you can according to Microsoft Forum:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/transfer-the-windows-8-license-from-the-old/aee82e47-0812-4f46-9bde-fac1b891ff13

But as also noted on the same forum, you may need to activate the license over the phone as internet activation may reject it, but can be overridden by phone activation.

You will need your serial number when contacting Microsoft Phone Support.