# How to reinstall retail Windows 8.1 Pro on another PC?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-key

I have retail Windows 8.1 Pro installed on my PC.

But now I want to uninstall this license from current PC and install Windows with that key on another. How could I do it?

Comment: I'm assuming there isn't a sticker with a key on the device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transferring a Windows 8 license and proper un- and reinstallation](http://superuser.com/questions/499088/transferring-a-windows-8-license-and-proper-un-and-reinstallation), [Can I Transfer The Windows 8 License of My Laptop to My Desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/794695/can-i-transfer-the-windows-8-license-of-my-laptop-to-my-desktop), [Migrating windows 8 license from one machine to another](http://superuser.com/questions/655103/migrating-windows-8-license-from-one-machine-to-another) and many more for Win7 (and probably Vista as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a **Retail**, not a **OEM**, license, you should be able to unregistered Windows 8.1 and then use your original key to install on the new system.

> **Warning:  Do the below at your own risk.**

### General Steps

1. Make sure you have your original product key and install media first.  If you cannot find your key, try using [Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/)
2. Deactivate your Windows 8.1 product key, by launching a **Command Prompt** [As an Administrator](https://superuser.com/a/497256/443938) and type in the following command: `slmgr.vbs /upk` or if that does not work try `slmgr.vbs -upk`.
3. Once done you can activate the new computer after install.

*Note:  Don't forget to put the key sticker on the new device.*

### Source

[How to Transfer your Windows 8.1 License to a New Computer](http://wind8apps.com/windows-8-license-transfer-to-new-computer/)

Answer (score 0):

If that key is NOT a multi use key or the number of uses (which are generally only concurrent use metric) then you will need to obtain another key (to stay legal)   OR  contact Microsoft and explain you lost your key or are having issues with reinstall on a new hard drive with same motherboard or the like.... Staying as close to the truth as is possible as once too much hardware has changed it is considered willful fraud even if the intent is purely benign.